# SQL getting leaf nodes of XML

Tags: sql, xml, ssms

I am trying to parse xml data for any leaf nodes
It is structured like this:

```
<xmlPlan>
    <myOp id='0' usage='0.75'>
        ....
        <myOp id='2' usage='0.45'>
            ...
        </myOp>
        <myOp id ='3' usage='0.30'>
            ...
        </myOp>
    </myOp>
    <myOp id='1' usage='0.35'>
        ...
    </myOp>
</xmlPlan>
```

I would need to select leaf nodes 1 2 and 3 and manipulate the usage numbers within those nodes.
Im using this to pull the xml from the db:

```
DECLARE @queryID INT = 1 

/* get xml with queryID */
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml = (SELECT TOP 1 myPlan FROM myTable 
                    WHERE stmtID in (@queryID))
```

Comment: `SELECT TOP 1 myPlan FROM myTable WHERE stmtID in (@queryID))` are you sure this is returning anything?

Comment: @vendettamit yes it is returning the correct xml

Comment: @vendettamit to follow up, I found that the XML root node contained a namespace (xmlns) that for some reason ended the query abruptly.

Answer (score 3):

Below will give you the nodes. But your example XML is not valid with attributes `a, b, c` in the nodes.

```
declare @a xml
declare @b xml

create table #t (
 v varchar(max)
)

set @a = ' <rootNode>
    <node>
        <node>
            some data
        </node>
        <node>
            some data
        </node>
    </node>
    <node>
        some data
    </node>
</rootNode>'

Insert into #t(v)
values(convert(varchar(max), @a))

Select @b = v from #t


SELECT c.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(max)') as 'node'
    , c.value('.', 'varchar(max)') as 'value'
from @b.nodes('/rootNode//*[not(*)] ') as a(c)

drop table #t
```

Comment: excellent. so this works when the xml is hard-coded as in the example. How can I get this to work when @a gets the xml from a SELECT statement? I get no results at all.

Comment: im still getting nothing returned.. im getting the xml similar to this method:

DECLARE \@queryID INT = 1
SET \@xml = (SELECT TOP 1 myPlan FROM myTable 
     WHERE stmtID in (\@queryID))

and im looking for any leaf nodes where the node name is myOp

Comment: Can you add more details like table structure, sample data and the query you are using so we can reproduce the issue?